# Any solution for file upload problem on Arduino ESP32 via http

Tags: http, file-upload, arduino, filesystems, arduino-esp32

**First the problem.**

The user can upload file from the web with ajax. If the file is relatively big, the uploading takes a while. If the user's connection is lost or something happens during the uploading process, the file is going to be damaged or empty.

**How should I secure the upload process so the file remains the same if it fails for some reason?**

**I'm using the following libraries on the Arduino ESP32:**

- [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer)
- [LITTLEFS](https://github.com/lorol/LITTLEFS)

*I have a basic file upload handler on my esp32 which looks like this:*

```
server.on("/uploading", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
  }, handleFileUpload);

void handleFileUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest * request, String filename,size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) {
  if (!index) {
    if (!filename.startsWith("/"))
      filename = "/" + filename;
    if (LITTLEFS.exists(filename)) {
      LITTLEFS.remove(filename);
    }
    uploadFile = LITTLEFS.open(filename, "w");
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    uploadFile.write(data[i]);
  }
  if (final) {
    uploadFile.close();
    if(filename == "/myHomeProgram.json"){initProgram = true;}
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(200, "text/plain", "File Uploaded;"+filename);
    response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    request->send(response);
  }

}
```

**This is working pretty well, the files are uploaded correctly 99% of the cases, but if it fails I lost the file data, or if some other part of the program wants to open the same file it fails too.
Should I write to a temporary file and after if it succeeded write the content to the intended file somehow?
Here is an example from client ( JS ) side:**

```
// Example call: 
saveFile(JSON.stringify(places),"/myHomeProgram.json","application/json");

function saveFile(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    form = new FormData();
    form.append("blob", file, filename);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploading', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
      }).done(function(resp){
        var response = resp.split(";");
        
        $(".saveIconGraph").removeClass("fas fa-spinner fa-spin");
        $(".saveIconGraph").addClass("far fa-save");

        if(response[1] == "/myHomeProgram.json"){
            toast("success","saveOk","progInfo",3500);
            showSaved();
            setTimeout(() => {
                $("#saveMe").fadeOut( "slow", function() { 
                    showSave();
                });
            }, 1000);
            initPlaces();
        }
      }).fail(function(resp){
        var response = resp.split(";");

        $(".saveIconGraph").removeClass("fas fa-spinner fa-spin");
        $(".saveIconGraph").addClass("far fa-save");
        
        if(response[1] == "/myHomeProgram.json"){
            toast("error","saveNotOk","progInfo",3500);
            showSaveError();
            $("#saveMeBtn").addClass("shakeEffect");
            setTimeout(() => {
                $("#saveMeBtn").removeClass("shakeEffect");
                showSave();
            }, 4500);
        }
      });
}
```

**I could save the file in a temporary char variable before write, and on the final I could match the size of the file and the temporary variable size and if it is not the same, roll back to the previous. Is this manageable?**

**Something like this:**

```
String uploadTemp = "";
inline boolean saveFileToTemp(String fileName){
  uploadTemp = "";
  File f = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "r");
  if (!f) {
    f.close();
    return false;
  }else{
    for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++){
      uploadTemp += (char)f.read();
    }
  }
  f.close();
  return true;
}

inline boolean revertBackFile(String fileName){
  File g = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "w");
  if (!g) {
    g.close();
    return false;
  }else{
    g.print(uploadTemp);
  }
  g.close();
  return true;
}

inline boolean matchFileSizes(String fileName,boolean isFileExists){
  boolean isCorrect = false;
  if(isFileExists){
    File writedFile = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "w");
    if( writedFile.size() == uploadTemp.length()){
      isCorrect = true;
    }else{
      isCorrect = false;
    }
    writedFile.close();
    return isCorrect;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}

void handleFileUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest * request, String filename,size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) {
  String webResponse;
  boolean error = false,isFileExists = false;
  if (!index) {
    if (!filename.startsWith("/"))
      filename = "/" + filename;
    if (LITTLEFS.exists(filename)) {
      isFileExists = true;
      // Save the file to a temporary String if it success we continue.
      if( saveFileToTemp(filename) ){
        LITTLEFS.remove(filename);
      }else{
        // If the file save was fail we abort everything.
        webResponse = "File NOT Uploaded " + filename;
        final = true;
        error = true;
      }
    }
    if( !error ){
      uploadFile = LITTLEFS.open(filename, "w");
    }
  }
  if( !error ){
    // Copy content to the actual file
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      uploadFile.write(data[i]);
    }
  }
  if (final) {
    uploadFile.close();
    if( !error ){
      if( matchFileSizes(filename,isFileExists) ){
        if(filename == "/myHomeProgram.json"){initProgram = true;}
        webResponse = "File Uploaded " + filename;
      }else{
        error = true;
        webResponse = "File length mismatch";
      }
    }
    if( error ){
      revertBackFile(filename);
    }
    Serial.println(webResponse);
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(200, "text/plain", webResponse);
    response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    request->send(response);
  }

}
```

Comment: With this test if i try to upload a file relatively big, like 50kb the watchdog got triggered, but working with small files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems to me that the problem solved.**

*I have managed to replace the String buffer with a char one in external memory. It seems stable but requires more testing. I'll post the solution but if anyone has a better approach feel free to comment here*.

**Thanks.**

```
char * uploadTemp;
inline boolean saveFileToTemp(String fileName){
  File f = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "r");
  if (!f) {
    f.close();
    return false;
  }else{
    size_t fileSize = f.size();
    uploadTemp = (char*)ps_malloc(fileSize + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){
      uploadTemp[i] = (char)f.read();
    }
    uploadTemp[fileSize] = '\0';
  }
  f.close();
  return true;
}

inline boolean revertBackFile(String fileName){
  File g = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "w");
  if (!g) {
    g.close();
    return false;
  }else{
    g.print(uploadTemp);
  }
  g.close();
  return true;
}

inline boolean matchFileSizes(String fileName,boolean isFileExists){
  boolean isCorrect = false;
  if(isFileExists){
    File writedFile = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "w");
    if( writedFile.size() == sizeof(uploadTemp)){
      isCorrect = true;
    }else{
      isCorrect = false;
    }
    writedFile.close();
    return isCorrect;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}

void handleFileUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest * request, String filename,size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) {
  boolean isFileExists = false,error = false;
  String webResponse = "";
  int httpStatus = 200;

  // Start of the file upload
  if (!index) {
    // Make sure that there is a / char at the start of the string
    if (!filename.startsWith("/")){ filename = "/" + filename; }
    // Check if the file exists
    if (LITTLEFS.exists(filename)) {
      isFileExists = true;
      // Get the file contents for safety reasons
      // If it succeded we can create a new file in the palce
      if( saveFileToTemp(filename) ){
        uploadFile = LITTLEFS.open(filename, "w");
      }else{
        // If we can not save it abort the upload process.
        webResponse = "File NOT Uploaded " + filename;
        final = true;error = true;
      }
    }
  }
  // If we have no error at this point, we can start to copy the content to the file.
  if( !error ){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      uploadFile.write(data[i]);
    }
  }
  // If no more data we can start responding back to the client
  if (final) {
    uploadFile.close();
    // Check if we got any error before.

    if( !error && matchFileSizes(filename,isFileExists) ){
      // Copyed file is the same, upload success.
      if(filename == "/myHomeProgram.json"){initProgram = true;}
      webResponse = "File Uploaded " + filename;
    }else{
      webResponse = "File length mismatch";
      revertBackFile(filename);
      httpStatus = 500;
    }

    free(uploadTemp);
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(httpStatus, "text/plain", webResponse);
    response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    request->send(response);

  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Yeah, so it was completely wrong.**

*I have to do the following things:*

- Save the file we want to upload if it exist into a temporary char array.
- Get the uploaded file into a temporary file on upload.
- If everything was a success, copy the contents of the temporary file to the intended file.
- If something fails, revert back the saved file to the original and report an error.

**Something like this ( still in test ):**

```
char * prevFileTemp;

inline boolean saveFileToTemp(String fileName){
  File f = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "r");
  if (!f) {
    f.close();
    return false;
  }else{
    size_t fileSize = f.size();
    prevFileTemp = (char*)ps_malloc(fileSize + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){
      prevFileTemp[i] = (char)f.read();
    }
  }
  f.close();
  return true;
}

inline boolean revertBackFile(String fileName){
  if (LITTLEFS.exists(fileName)) {
    Serial.println("Reverting back the file");
    File g = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "w");
    if (!g) {
      g.close();
      return false;
    }else{
      g.print(prevFileTemp);
    }
    g.close();
  }
  return true;
}


static const inline boolean copyContent(String fileName){
  File arrivedFile  = LITTLEFS.open(uploadTemp, "r");
  File newFile      = LITTLEFS.open(fileName, "w");
  // Check if we can open the files as intended.
  if( !arrivedFile || !newFile){
    revertBackFile(fileName);
    return false;
  }
  // Copy one file content to another.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arrivedFile.size(); i++) { newFile.write( (char)arrivedFile.read() ); }
  // Check the sizes, if no match, abort mission.
  if( newFile.size() != arrivedFile.size()){ return false; }
  
  arrivedFile.close();newFile.close();
  return true;
}

boolean isFileExists = false,uploadError = false,newFileArrived = false;
String webResponse = "",newArrivalFileName = "";
int httpStatus = 200;

inline void resetVariables(){
  isFileExists  = false;
  uploadError   = false;
  webResponse   = "";
  httpStatus    = 200;
}


void handleFileUpload(AsyncWebServerRequest * request, String filename,size_t index, uint8_t *data, size_t len, bool final) {
  // Start file upload process
  if (!index) {
    // Reset all the variables
    resetVariables();
    // Make sure that there is a '/' char at the start of the string
    if (!filename.startsWith("/")){ filename = "/" + filename; }
    // Open the temporary file for content copy if it is exist
    if (LITTLEFS.exists(filename)) {
      if( saveFileToTemp(filename) ){
        uploadFile = LITTLEFS.open(uploadTemp, "w");
      }else{
        // If we can not save it abort the upload process.
        webResponse = "File NOT Uploaded " + filename;
        final = true;uploadError = true;
      }
    }
  }
  // If we have no error at this point, we can start to copy the content to the temporary file.
  if( !uploadError ){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      uploadFile.write(data[i]);
    }
  }
  // If no more data we can start responding back to the client
  if (final) {
    if (!filename.startsWith("/")){ filename = "/" + filename; }
    uploadFile.close();
    if( !uploadError && copyContent(filename) ){
      webResponse = "File Uploaded " + filename;
    }else{
      webResponse = "File length mismatch";
      revertBackFile(filename);
      httpStatus = 500;
    }
    free(prevFileTemp);
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(httpStatus, "text/plain", webResponse);
    response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    request->send(response);
  }

}
```